# Get dynamic replacement with preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

This is my url:

```
ftp://dynamic_text:user_password@my-ftp-domain.com/so-on/param
```

My regex will turn it into this:

```
ftp://*****:*****@my-ftp-domain.com/so-on/param
```

Note that the url can start with either `ftp` or `http`.

regex:

My regex below will always return `ftp` regardless if my url started with `http`.

```
preg_replace('@(ftp|http)://(.*:.*)\@@', 'ftp://****:****@', $url);
```

Now my question is: how can I modify my code, so that it will dynamically return `ftp` or `http` depending on how my url started.

I read about [Named Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refext.html), but I wasn't able to solve it.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: It the URL starts with `http` then output is `http://****:***@so on` or It the URL starts with `ftp` then output is `ftp://****:***@so on` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change the `ftp` part in your replacement to `$1` to get the value of the first group, e.g.

```
preg_replace('@(ftp|http)://(.*:.*)\@@', '$1://****:****@', $url);
                                        //^^
```

Comment: That's all! Learned something new. Thanks gent. +1. I'll accept it 11 minutes later.